# Display how many users are logged in today

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I want to display on a page how many users are logged in today so, this is my query from my sql server where shows how many users are logged in today,

```
SELECT userId, username, primaryType FROM [dbo].[users] where CONVERT(date, created) = convert(date, getdate())
```

and this is where are call the query from sql server in my code,

```
public void LoggedinUsers()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionInfo))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LoggedinUsers", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();
            }

            conn.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

And, I don't know if i need a parameter or something, I want the value to return in string, all I need the code in c# to get the value from bool to string, so if its 1 user than one, this is the main goal, I want to display in my page for example today are logged in one users or two depends how many users are logged in base mysql.

Comment: I am guessing that you are really using SQL Server and not MySQL, so I changed the tag.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The query you show doesn't return numbers, it returns rows - one for each user _created_ today. You're then executing a non-query, so that's not going to return anything - other than the number of rows affected, which for a SELECT is -1, see the docs. And then you want to convert the integer 1 to the word "one"?

Comment: Yes, the query is to get the users which are logged in today, and if its 10 users logged in today i want to get in string ten to display in the page, Today are logged in ten users, this is my main goal. do i need to add something in the query to get the value in string? Thanks @CodeCaster

Comment: That sql doesn't really look like it's counting logins.

Comment: Then start by reading an SQL tutorial, then dive into the SqlCommand documentation and finally do a web search for "C# number as text". And don't add the MySQL tag again, this is not MySQL.

Comment: While a deep dive is probably most useful, I think you could get away with either: looking into using .ExecuteReader() to get (and then count) the rows returned by the stored procedure, or: rewrite the sp (or make a new one) which selects count(*) in stead of the columns and then make use of ExecuteScalar()

Comment: First of all, the query is not counting the loggedIn users. Second, your method is returning void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

Create a new bool column in your users table, name it "Active" - update this column value to true when a user login. Set the value to False when users logout.

SQL query:

```
Select count(*) from dbo.users where Active = 1
```

C# : You need to call this function on page load of your master page (assuming that your loggedin display is in master page).

```
public int LoggedinUsers()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionInfo))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LoggedinUsers", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open(); 
                int result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();
            } 
            conn.Dispose(); 
        }
        return result;
    }
```

To convert this integer to Text , go through this link(I googled for you):
https://forums.asp.net/t/1995435.aspx?How+to+convert+Number+to+word+using+Sql+Query+with+standard+US+as+UK+Fromat

Comment: _"Set the value to False when users logout."_ - that won't work, web users generally don't log out.

Comment: @CodeCaster Hmm.. Something to think about, I think we can register if the window is closed, using javascript ?

Comment: A browser or computer can crash. The general approach in a web application is to set a LastActive timestamp upon every action for a user session, then consider anyone who had activity on their sesison in the past N minutes.